# Copy field values of one object to another object (Opp to Contract)

Tags: apex, trigger, sosl

Hi Want to transfer the value from Opp to contract.

Once Opp stage is CLOSED WON it is converted into New Contract.

Req:

Once Contract is created, i want to transfer/copy the same field values from opp to contract (Field name -> Date, Name, Amount1, Amount2 etc).

Comment: and why not use Process Builder?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to such problem would involve usage of **Batch Apex** or trigger or both. I would go for Batch job that would run on nightly basis to do such task.

- Create a Batch class that runs daily and fetches the Opportunity that are in Closed Won Stage.
- Query the required Opportunity fields in the **start** method, as per your conditions. Don't miss out to add all the fields you want to copy. For best results, only use fields that really matter.
- Initialize your Contract Object in **execute** method and assign field values from Opportunity to Contract, according to your field mapping. Lastly, perform an **upsert** operation on Contract based on an **External Id** field. You need to create an External Id field to perform an upsert operation otherwise it won't work in your case. This would keep both the objects in sync. You can do something like this:

  ```
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope){
  List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract>();
  for(Opportunity s : scope){
  contracts.add(new Contract(field1__c = s.field__1,field2__c = s.field2__c,ExternalIdField__c = s.Id //And so on ..);
  }
  Database.upsert(contracts,Contract.ExternalIdField__c,false);
  }
  ```

**Importance of using external Id field:**
`ExternalIdField__c = s.Id` - After you create a Contract storing the OpportunityId in this External Id field, the upsert will check if a Contract already exist for an Opportunity. If it does, it will update the Contract or else insert new one.

Use **Database.upsert** to allow partial success. The false parmeter takes care of that. You can also loop over the result to check whatever you want to. Use `Database.Upsertresult` for such case.

Hope this helps .. Let me know if this works !!

Comment: Hi @heisnberg - My query is that, once the contract is created for any closed won opp, need to transfer the value from the (Opp to Contract) field, as same fields are in both the object (Opp and Contract). If i will execute batch for the same, on in the run time it will not work. So i want something which will work in run time environment also.

Comment: Yes, so that means you need to either update Contracts or insert them based on Opportunity. Copying values means the same right?

Comment: Fields in Opp (Date (5/12/12), Name (ABC), Amount1 (100$) , Amount2 (20$)). So once contract is created for the opp then the same value should be populated in that contract (Date (5/12/12), Name (ABC), Amount1 (100$) , Amount2 (20$)). As i had created the same fields in the contract also.

Comment: I am not getting your point. The batch will run nightly basis to check all the Opportunities in closed won. Based on the data it will upsert the Contracts. What am I missing? Please explain more.

Comment: You want to create Contracts based on Opportunity right?

Comment: yes. i had applied trigger on opp, and applied on all the Opp whose stage converted into Closed won. that is working fine for me.. now my query is to transfer the value from Opp to Contract (which is created based on closed won)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24813/discussion-between-heisenberg-and-sachin-kumar).